# How to update object periodically on Spark workers?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I have a requirement in my Spark application where i need to update the variable periodically which will be used by worker code.

For more concrete understanding, i need to put my data to Kinesis shards with equal partitioning. The number of kinesis shards can increase or decrease any time, so i should always get correct number of shards since my partition key is

`System.currentTimeMillis % shardSize`

But i dont want to query this always, so something like java.util.TimerTask will help, which i can broadcast to workers.

This is the code i need to run periodically and broadcast the value to slaves.

```
def fetchNumberOfShards(): Integer = {
    val describeStreamRequest = new DescribeStreamRequest()
    describeStreamRequest.setStreamName(streamName)
    val describeStreamResult = kinesisClient.describeStream( describeStreamRequest )
    val shards = describeStreamResult.getStreamDescription().getShards()
    return shards.size()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to just use a random partition key with uniform distribution, say System.currentTimeMillis. You don't actually need to specify which shard to use and so don't need to track how many shards there are.

EDIT

Given that you haven't had luck with that, broadcast variables will solve this for you:

> Broadcast variables allow the programmer to keep a read-only variable cached on each machine

```
// executes on driver
scala> var broadcastVar = sc.broadcast(numShards)
broadcastVar: org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast[Int] = Broadcast(0)

// retrieve value on worker
scala> broadcastVar.value
res0: Int = 5
```

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables

The driver can update `broadcastVar` periodically as you need, workers can only read the `broadcastVar.value`. You can then use the `broadcastVar.value` to plug into your shard hash function.

Comment: I tried that, somehow Kinesis does not distribute partition keys uniformly. Especially when resharding happens. Thats why this code.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include broadcast variables, which will solve this for you